# Jira ServiceDesk API - response suddenly missing the field emailAddress

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am getting a list of users in an organisation from the Jira ServiceDesk API, as [documented on this page](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/#api-rest-servicedeskapi-organization-organizationId-user-get).

So far this is working as expected but today all off a sudden the code is broken. That is to say; the results im getting from the API have changed. As the docs state i SHOULD be getting values that include the field emailAddress. However since today i am getting the right users, but there is no longer an emailAddress field. The following is the result (structure) i'm recieving:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "start": 0,
  "limit": 50,
  "isLastPage": true,
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://someprefix.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/organization/1/user?start=0&limit=50",
    "base": "BaseURL",
    "context": ""
  },
  "values": [
    {
      "accountId": "123456:SomeGUID",
      "name": "SomeUserName",
      "key": "someusername",
      "displayName": "Some Username",
      "active": true,
      "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
      "_links": {
        "jiraRest": "LinkToTheThisUser",
        "avatarUrls": {
          "48x48": "LinkTo48X48Url",
          "24x24": "LinkTo24X24Url",
          "16x16": "LinkTo16X16Url",
          "32x32": "LinkTo32X32Url"
        },
        "self": "LinkToThisResource"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I asked to check the setting `User email visibility` and it is currently set to `logged in users` only.

**My question:**

- Why is this field suddenly missing from the API? Is there or are there settings i'm unaware off that influence this field being present or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems [this is by design to keep in line with GDPR guidelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/blog/2019/05/upcoming-changes-to-atlassian-account-profiles). Long story short; emailAddress will no longer be reliably part of the API's since a user now has to consent to it. If not all users emailAddresses are reliably part of the response this makes for a poor field of comparison in synchronization applications.

> **Which profile information will apps be able to access?**
>
> Any personal information users set as Anyone will be available for apps to use. For
>   example, apps will be able to access this information, store it, and
>   show it to other users.
>
> Users' local times and locations will always be available to apps,
>   regardless of their visibility settings. This lets apps customize
>   their experiences.
>
> Users' email addresses will be available to some apps that have been
>   approved by Atlassian. Note that if a user chooses to set their email
>   address to Anyone, then any installed apps will be able to use it.
>
> When users install apps, the apps will request that they consent to
>   share their profile information with the apps. If they consent, the
>   apps will have access to all of their profile information. This is not
>   applicable to admins.

However. There will be a new API giving access to user emailAddresses regardless of user settings. Access to this API is restricted to approved applications. More about this can be found [on this page](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/guidelines-for-requesting-access-to-email-address/27603).

> In order to apply for access to this API the app must meet all current
>   requirements for being listed on Atlassian Marketplace (even if the
>   app is not listed on Atlassian Marketplace).
>
> This means:
>
> - The app developer has provided a privacy policy
> - The app developer has provided a customer terms of use agreement
> - The app developer must signal whether or not the app collects and    stores personal data.
> - If the app is storing personal data the app must report the    accountIDs that have been collected and stored every 15 days.